# OS X - Quit Program Before Connecting to LAN

Tags: macos, lan

I need my computer to check for a particular program when I plug in a LAN cable, and quit it (if it runs) before connecting to the internet.
My LAN connection has static IP address.
I have absolutely no idea how to do this...
Any ideas?

Comment: Please be precise "quit it", what is, "it" exactly?"?

Comment: Sounds like all you need is [Little Snitch](https://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html), if you want to prevent it phoning home.

Comment: Ramhound - I meant quit the program...

Answer (score -2):

Little Snitch did exactly what I needed. I assigned a different profile to LAN network which blocks the program from the Internet, so I didn't have to quit it at all.